# Manipulating page scrolling when returning a View in an ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site where I want one of the Views I return to be automatically scroll to a certain point.

The part of the site where I want this to occur works sort of like a forum - there are "threads" that contain "posts". A user can either browse to the whole paginated thread or can browse to a specific post, using its ID. When a user browses to a specific post, I want to show the regular thread interface, then browse to the page that the post is on and scroll down to the post.

**Is it possible to somehow automatically scroll down to a certain point when returning a View from an action in an ASP.NET MVC site?** If so, how do I do this?

*NOTE: One solution to this problem that I've found is how Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites do it: each answer to a question can be linked to by adding `#ID` to the URL. If it's impossible to automatically scroll down when returning a View, I would implement this instead, but I don't understand how to use such an approach when there are multiple pages and the post in question isn't on the current page.*

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243543/manipulating-page-scrolling-when-returning-a-view-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site/3243587#3243587), I'm currently planning to implement it with the URL looking like this: `example.com/forum/[ForumID]/thread/[ThreadID]/post/[PostID]#[PostID]`. In my Action, I figure out what page of the Thread the Post is on, and then I return all the Posts from that page to the View.

However, I noticed something special in how Stack Overflow solves this problem. Try going to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57170 - it ends up sending you to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57155/gravatar-bugs-and-improvements-in-chat/57170#57170.

**How is the above implemented?** This is ***exactly* what I want to accomplish**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript in your View to achieve automatic scrolling, with something like the jQuery ScrollTo plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). Attach it to your page load event and target your desired post.

However, the simplest way (and most cross-browser compatible) would be like how StackOverflow does it, with the #ID in the URL.

Comment: @Chris: about the `#ID` way: how do I make it work across pages? After all, I should only load one page at a time, right?

Comment: Make the link to the post the full link. So instead of your href being (for example) just #ID, use http://example.com/forum/2/thread/100/Page/2/#ID

Comment: Unless I find another solution, I will implement it to be like `example.com/forum/[ForumID]/thread/[ThreadID]/post/[PostID]#[PostID]`. This is because hardcoding the page number in the link isn't really good, as the page number can change (in my system). I think I will first read the PostID, return the page that that Post is on, , and then the `#` will activate.

Comment: Quick question: I understand how this works in most cases, but I noticed that on Stack Overflow there's something special, which is the exact thing that I'm looking for. **Try going to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57170/** - it ends up sending you to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57155/gravatar-bugs-and-improvements-in-chat/57170#57170. **How is this implemented?** This is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: It's done by looking up the answer ID and redirecting to the correct question page with a #ID to jump to the correct answer. Essentially it does what it sounds like you were thinking of implementing.

Comment: @Chris - how do they add a `#` to the URL when redirecting? Could you give me some sample code for that?